# Angular cli load script on demand

Tags: javascript, angular

I need help.
I'm creating a project and I'm having a problem getting my template to work.
I created a component for the Header and one for the menu. The menu is a sidebar and is hidden when you open the page. only after login the menu appears. But javascript does not work after that.

```
.angular-cli.json
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "project": {
        "name": "ticket.web.api"
      },
      "apps": [
        {
          "root": "src",
          "outDir": "dist",
          "assets": ["assets", "favicon.ico"],
          "index": "index.html",
          "main": "main.ts",
          "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
          "test": "test.ts",
          "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
          "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
          "prefix": "app",
          "styles": [
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            "./assets/fonts/feather/style.min.css",
            "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
            "./assets/fonts/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css",
            "./assets/vendors/css/extensions/pace.css",
            "./assets/vendors/css/ui/prism.min.css",
            "./assets/css/app.min.css",
            "./assets/css/core/menu/menu-types/vertical-menu.min.css",
            "./assets/css/core/colors/palette-gradient.min.css",
            "./assets/vendors/css/forms/icheck/icheck.css",
            "./assets/vendors/css/forms/icheck/custom.css",
            "./assets/css/pages/login-register.min.css",
            "styles.css"
          ],
          "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
            "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "../node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/min/perfect-scrollbar.min.js",
            "./assets/vendors/js/unison/js/unison.js",
            "../node_modules/block-ui/jquery.blockUI.js",
            "../node_modules/jquery-match-height/dist/jquery.matchHeight.js",
            "./assets/vendors/js/slide-menu/slide-menu.js",
            "../node_modules/screenfull/dist/screenfull.js",
            "../node_modules/pace-js/pace.min.js",
            "../node_modules/prismjs/prism.js",
            "./assets/vendors/js/forms/icheck/icheck.min.js",
            "./assets/vendors/js/forms/validation/jqBootstrapValidation.js",
            "./assets/js/scripts/forms/form-login-register.min.js",

            **"./assets/js/core/app-menu.min.js",
            "./assets/js/core/app.min.js",
            "./assets/js/scripts/customizer.min.js"**
          ],
          "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
          "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        }
      ],
      "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
          "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
      },
      "lint": [
        {
          "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
        },
        {
          "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
          "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
        },
        {
          "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
          "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
        }
      ],
      "test": {
        "karma": {
          "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
      },
      "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "css",
        "component": {}
      }
    }
```

```
Header Component
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
    <nav class="header-navbar navbar-expand-md navbar navbar-with-menu fixed-top navbar-light navbar-shadow" ***ngIf="url != '/sign-in'"** >
           <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row">
        <li class="nav-item mobile-menu d-md-none mr-auto">
          **<a class="nav-link nav-menu-main menu-toggle hidden-xs" href="#">**
            <i class="ft-menu font-large-1"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']">
            <img class="brand-logo" alt="stack admin logo" src="assets/images/logo/stack-logo.png">
            <h2 class="brand-text">Stack</h2>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-md-none">
          <a class="nav-link open-navbar-container" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-mobile">
            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-container content">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-mobile">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto float-left">
          <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block" *ngIf="userLogged">
            <a class="nav-link nav-menu-main menu-toggle hidden-xs" href="#">
              <i class="ft-menu"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown nav-item mega-dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</a>
            <ul class="mega-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu row">
              <li class="col-md-2">
                <h6 class="dropdown-menu-header text-uppercase mb-1">
                  <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> News</h6>
                <div id="mega-menu-carousel-example">
                  <div>
                    <img class="rounded img-fluid mb-1" src="assets/images/slider/slider-2.png" alt="First slide">
                    <a class="news-title mb-0" href="#">Poster Frame PSD</a>
                    <p class="news-content">
                      <span class="font-small-2">January 26, 2016</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="col-md-3">
                <h6 class="dropdown-menu-header text-uppercase">
                  <i class="fa fa-random"></i> Drill down menu</h6>
                <ul class="drilldown-menu">
                  <li class="menu-list">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="layout-2-columns.html">
                          <i class="ft-file"></i> Page layouts & Templates</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <i class="ft-align-left"></i> Multi level menu</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i> Second level</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-lemon-o"></i> Second level menu</a>
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                  <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Third level</a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                  <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> Third level</a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                  <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Third level</a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Third level</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-hdd-o"></i> Second level, third link</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Second level, fourth link</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="color-palette-primary.html">
                          <i class="ft-camera"></i> Color pallet system</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="sk-2-columns.html">
                          <i class="ft-edit"></i> Page starter kit</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="changelog.html">
                          <i class="ft-minimize-2"></i> Change log</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                          <i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i> Customer support center</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="col-md-3">
                <h6 class="dropdown-menu-header text-uppercase">
                  <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i> Accordion</h6>
                <div id="accordionWrap" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                  <div class="card border-0 box-shadow-0 collapse-icon accordion-icon-rotate">
                    <div class="card-header p-0 pb-2 border-0" id="headingOne" role="tab">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionWrap" href="#accordionOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordionOne">Accordion Item #1</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-collapse collapse show" id="accordionOne" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" aria-expanded="true">
                      <div class="card-content">
                        <p class="accordion-text text-small-3">Caramels dessert chocolate cake pastry jujubes bonbon. Jelly wafer jelly beans. Caramels chocolate
                          cake liquorice cake wafer jelly beans croissant apple pie.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-header p-0 pb-2 border-0" id="headingTwo" role="tab">
                      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionWrap" href="#accordionTwo" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-controls="accordionTwo">Accordion Item #2</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-collapse collapse" id="accordionTwo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" aria-expanded="false">
                      <div class="card-content">
                        <p class="accordion-text">Sugar plum bear claw oat cake chocolate jelly tiramisu dessert pie. Tiramisu macaroon muffin jelly
                          marshmallow cake. Pastry oat cake chupa chups.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-header p-0 pb-2 border-0" id="headingThree" role="tab">
                      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionWrap" href="#accordionThree" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-controls="accordionThree">Accordion Item #3</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-collapse collapse" id="accordionThree" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree" aria-expanded="false">
                      <div class="card-content">
                        <p class="accordion-text">Candy cupcake sugar plum oat cake wafer marzipan jujubes lollipop macaroon. Cake dragée jujubes donut
                          chocolate bar chocolate cake cupcake chocolate topping.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="col-md-4">
                <h6 class="dropdown-menu-header text-uppercase mb-1">
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact Us</h6>
                <form ngControl="ControlName" class="form form-horizontal">
                  <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="inputName1">Name</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputName1" placeholder="John Doe">
                          <div class="form-control-position pl-1">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="inputEmail1">Email</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                          <input class="form-control" type="email" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="john@example.com">
                          <div class="form-control-position pl-1">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="inputMessage1">Message</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage1" rows="2" placeholder="Simple Textarea"></textarea>
                          <div class="form-control-position pl-1">
                            <i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 mb-1">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="button">
                          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i> Send</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>          
          **<li class="nav-item nav-search">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-search" href="#">
              <i class="ficon ft-search"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="search-input">
              <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Explore Stack...">
            </div>
          </li>**
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-right">
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-language nav-item">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="dropdown-flag" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></i>
              <span class="selected-language">Idioma</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-flag">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></i> English</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"></i> French</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-cn"></i> Chinese</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-de"></i> German</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-user nav-item">
            <a *ngIf="!userLogged" class=" nav-link nav-menu-main menu-toggle hidden-xs" [routerLink]="['/sign-in']">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Entrar</a>
            <a *ngIf="userLogged" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="user-name">{{ user.cn }}</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="user-profile.html">
                <i class="ft-user"></i> Edit Profile</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="email-application.html">
                <i class="ft-mail"></i> My Inbox</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="user-cards.html">
                <i class="ft-check-square"></i> Task</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="chat-application.html">
                <i class="ft-message-square"></i> Chats</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> -->
              <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">
                <i class="ft-power"></i> Sair</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
Menu Component
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
    **<div class="main-menu menu-fixed menu-light menu-accordion menu-shadow menu-bordered" data-scroll-to-active="true" *ngIf="url != '/sign-in' && userLogged">**
      <div class="main-menu-content">
        <ul class="navigation navigation-main" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
          <li class="navigation-header">
            <span>General</span>
          <i class=" ft-minus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-ori`enter code here`ginal-title="General"></i>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
           <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">
            <i class="ft-home"></i>
            <span class="menu-title" data-i18n="">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
```

```
Menu Component
------------------------------------------------------------------------


    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

    import * as $ from 'jquery';

    import { AuthService } from '../../../security/services/auth.service';
    import { User } from '../../../security/model/auth.model';
    import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { THROW_IF_NOT_FOUND } from '@angular/core/src/di/injector';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-header',
      templateUrl: './header.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
    })
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      isLoggedIn$: Observable;
      userLogged: boolean;
      url: string;
      user: User;

      constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
        router.events
          .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
          .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
            this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
            this.isLoggedIn$.subscribe(res => (this.userLogged = res));
            this.url = event['url'];

            const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            if (this.userLogged === false) {
              body.classList.remove('menu-expanded');
            } else {
              body.classList.add('menu-expanded');
            }
            this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

          });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Header Component - ngOnInit');
      }

      ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('Header Component - ngAfterViewInit');
        console.log('---------------------------------------');
         $.getScript('../../../../assets/js/core/app.min.js').done(function() {
            console.log('Header app.min.js');
          });
          $.getScript('../../../../assets/js/core/app-menu.min.js').done(
            function() {
              console.log('Header app-menu.min.js');
            }
          );
        $.getScript('../../../../assets/js/scripts/customizer.min.js').done(
          function() {
            console.log('Header customizer.min.js');
          }
        );
      }

      logout() {
        this.authService.logout();
      }
    }
```

Whenever I go to the login screen I hide the navigation bar and sidebar, and when it comes in and shows again, the script no longer works. When I go to see the inspector, the script disappears from the element.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you properly .But from the amount i understood your problem you should try to add your css or script file in index.html

or if you want to load some script file dynamically to some specific component.you can use these line of code.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScript('your path');
 } 

    loadScript(src){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    script.src = src;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to use a service and use ReplaySubject to not add each time the same script. To use it, you have to call loadExternals with an array of string.

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { forkJoin, Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ExternalScriptLoading {
  private libraries: { [url: string]: ReplaySubject<unknown> } = {};

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: Document) {}

  public loadExternals(externals: string[]): Observable<unknown> {
    return forkJoin(externals.map((external: string) => this.inject(external)));
  }

  private inject(link: string): Observable<unknown> {
    if (this.libraries[link]) {
      return this.libraries[link].asObservable();
    }

    this.libraries[link] = new ReplaySubject();

    this.injectScript(link);

    return this.libraries[link].asObservable();
  }

  private injectScript(url: string): void {
    const script: HTMLScriptElement = this.document.createElement('script');

    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    script.defer = true;
    script.onload = () => {
      this.libraries[url].next();
      this.libraries[url].complete();
    };

    this.document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

Source: https://netbasal.com/loading-external-libraries-on-demand-in-angular-9dad45701801